# Expected output from an RM-1501 RS232 interface?

Tags: c++, serial-port

I have an old [RM-1501 digital tachometer](http://newzealand.rs-online.com/mobile/search/searchBrowseAction.html?method=getProduct&R=3850577) which I'm using to try to identify the speed of an object.

According to [the manual](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0bf5/0900766b80bf5325.pdf) I should be able to read the data over a serial link. Unfortunately, I don't appear to be able to get any sensible output from the device (never gives a valid speed). I think it might be a signalling problem because disconnecting the CTS line starts to get some data through..

Has anyone ever developed anything for one of these / had any success?

Comment: You've obviously got your serial socket set up. Do you have the correct port settings, baud rate, stop bit etc?

Comment: This looks like a hardware issue, so expect this question to get closed, but to avoid that you should include perhaps some detail of the code you are using; tagging it C++ but including no C++ or even software specific information is likely to accelerate closure.  There are any number of ways of interfacing with the serial port, many are OS specific or rely on third-party API's; that information may be useful.

Comment: I'm rapidly coming to the same conclusion (that it's a hardware cnofiguration) so perhaps it's best to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried every combination of hardware control (both enabled and disabled) I could think of so I think it must be a hardware problem. Removnig the CLS link between PC and the device solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The manual does not specify that flow control is used.  Open the port with hardware/software flow control disabled.

The manual does not specify the connection - whether it is DTE<->DCE or Null Modem; are you using the cable supplied with the device?

Answer (score 1):

I don;t know if this info is still use full. but I tried with even parity and got the data. The protocol in the document is incorrect i think (at least for the version I am using now) it is a 5 character display (9999) we only need 3 byte to get the required information the 4th byte should always be zero. Hence with 0x0D as starting and following 6 byte makes the entire packet i.e., 0xD0 B1 B2 B3 D1 D2 D3. B1,B2 and B3 bytes contain the divisor, status, units, functions and error flags. Where as the last three byte (D1,D2,D3) are the data, with D1 as LSB and D3 as MSB. I would also like to add that may be the manufacture changed the Firmware with out changing the user manual :). so my version of the protocol might be true some and wrong for others

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually sending data to indicate speed, or is it providing make / break on one of the pins?